# Querying for a specific language and if not found use default one instead

Tags: postgresql, query, localization

I currently store all language data (including default language) in my database. Generally a simple query making the assumption the language exists is as simple as doing:

```
SELECT a.artifact_id, 
       a.base_atk, 
       a.base_hp, 
       a.max_atk, 
       a.max_hp, 
       b.name, 
       c."class", 
       b.lore_description, 
       b.skill_description 
FROM GameArtifact a 
JOIN GameArtifactNameDesc b 
    ON a.artifact_id = b.artifact_id AND b.locale = 'en-US'
JOIN GameClassTranslation c 
    ON c.identifier = a."exclusive" AND c.locale = 'en-US';
```

And a result from that said query:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----+-------------------------------------------------------------------
artifact_id       | abyssal-crown
base_atk          | 15
base_hp           | 54
max_atk           | 195
max_hp            | 702
name              | Abyssal Crown
class             | Mage
lore_description  | May those ruled by the crown walk the road of corruption forever. +
                  | - Witch Reinwood, hung high up on the stake
skill_description | 12.0% (24.0%) chance to stun the enemy for 1 turn after attacking.
```

The issue is, what if the language (which is set on the application) is not found? How can I set it to use a default language (let's say: es-AR) and query for that language? Or what if there's translation for that language in **one table** but not in **both**?

I thought of two approaches:

**Approach #1**

Doing the query presented above and if it doesn't return anything, query again using the default language which I can be certain there's data of in the database.

This doesn't sound convincing and nice to do.

**Approach #2**

Cut off the short tables and do their translations on the application. Which in this case GameClassTranslation, which only contains 49 rows, 7 languages so 7 rows per language but which might expand in the future.

This also doesn't sound convincing from the point of keeping everything in one place rather than split everywhere.

---

Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: Please have a look at: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving next example:

```
create table a (id int, description text);
create table b (id int, lang text, description text, default_lang int);
insert into a values (1, 'Yo vivo en Barcelona');
insert into b values 
(1, 'en-US', 'I am living in Barcelona', 0), 
(1, 'es-AR', 'Yo vivo en Barcelona', 1);
```

If you table have a default text for the default language you could use a LEFT JOIN and COALESCE in this way:

```
select
    a.id,
    coalesce(b.description, a.description) as description
from
    a
left join
    b
    on b.id = a.id and b.lang = 'en-US';
```

> ```
> id | description             
> -: | :-----------------------
>  1 | I am living in Barcelona
> ```

Or you could add a `default_lang` column in translations table and use a LATERAL JOIN with LIMIT 1:

```
select
    a.id,
    coalesce(b.description, a.description) as description
from
    a
join lateral
    (select id, description
     from   b
     where  lang = 'en-EN' or lang = 'es-AR'
     order by default_lang
     limit 1) b on true
```

> ```
> id | description         
> -: | :-------------------
>  1 | Yo vivo en Barcelona
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=fc9d675dc89dd80eccd452dcb389d1a8)*